# What object should be referenced to use the Sheets property?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to look at cells in column A, and grab the number of employees for that company from a Google search (column A would be "company name number of employees"). Here's the code (need reference to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library):

```
Sub GetHits()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim var As String
Dim var1 As Object
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement As Object
Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set oElement = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = oElement(i).innerText
        i = i + 1

        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

> Run time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set

comes in at this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = oElement(i).innertext
```

I've tried changing it to `Worksheets` `Set` `With`. Perhaps because it's VBA rather than Vb.net? I read something about `Set` being different between the two versions.

I don't think it's because I'm missing quotation marks, as in another run-time error 91 problem on here, or because of misspelling, etc.

oElement has been set as an object on line 9 - `Dim oElement As Object`.

Here's a sample of Column A:

[image]

Comment: You're positive there are at least 3 `oElement`s? IIRC it'll index those elements starting at `0`.

Comment: That would be the number of companies in column A? Yes, I've got 1,300 total, but I've got a sample sheet (in a new book, so Sheet1) with 10 just for testing purposes. I had a different program I was messing around with but that only gave me the digits after the comma, and only sometimes, so I switched to this, which I think should work, but I keep getting that error

Comment: I am not sure what you have in column A, but I tried to run your code with just "Google" as the company, and the HTML returned did *not* have a class `Z0LcW` at all. Are you sure that class exists in the HTML you get returned? What's one string you're looking up?

Comment: For example:
21st Century Fox number of employees
Will give you a search page with a big box around 22,400
I checked the page source on about a dozen of similar searches, and I get this div class:
<div class="Z0LcW">22,400

Comment: So column A is drawn from a Salesforce report, where it had a bunch of information on contacts at different companies. I started with 6,000, removed duplicates, and got around 1,300 unique company names. Then I did a simple company name &" "& number of employees to create a new cell. So they look like "3M number of employees", "99 cent store number of employees", "A. Schulman Inc. number of employees". etc. Oh and they've been copied and pasted with just values of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = oElement(i).innerText
```

It's not clear why, when searching for a single company at a time, the returned page would have at least the same number of matching div's as the Excel row you're on at the time?

There's no connection between your sheet and the page content, other than the company name.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = oElement(0).innerText
```

might be more appropriate.

This works for me:

```
Sub GetHits()
    Dim url As String
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object
    Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument, i As Long
    Dim oElement As Object, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    For i = 2 To sht.Range("A" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & _
              " number of employees"
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", _
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
            .send
            Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
            oHtml.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
        End With

        Set oElement = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")
        If oElement.Length > 0 Then sht.Range("B" & i) = oElement(0).innerText
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear why it's an error? Haha so I'm not going crazy? There's only one result for <div class="Z0LcW"> per page per search.
0 returns the same error unfortunately

Comment: Then you want `oElement(0)`

Comment: You also have `i = i + 1` inside your loop, so you're skipping every other row. Delete that or use `Step 2` in your for loop if you really want that behavior.

Comment: ```oElement(0)``` Returns the same error unfortunately

Comment: See the other answer that fixed it for me.

Comment: Hey Tim, sorry, I have 19 reputation so I can't ask you this in chat, but this was working great yesterday, tried it on my sample sheet, was fantastic, then tried it on my big sheet, let it run for a while but it eventually froze and couldn't get it to respond, and now when I try to run it nothing happens! Like zero, zilch nadda. No error codes, the program doesn't stop or anything, it just seems to run, but return nothing. Any idea why that might be? Automated response from google for trying to access too much in too little time? I can still search google separately though. Very confused!

Comment: Quite possible they rate-limited or blocked you for too many searches in too short a time.

Comment: Any chance you could copy what's above and do a very quick trial run? I tried it on a colleagues computer and got the same response - program ran for about the right amount of time, but no actual outputs. 
Figured if it was an IP thing that would take care of it, but maybe they stopped anyone on the network? But it hasn't stopped me from just doing normal Google searches, whether through Internet Explorer, or chrome or whatever. C'est très bizarre

Comment: And in fact this other, very similar program works on my computer (well, until it gets to a search without ```div class="Z0LcW"```,"AARP number of employees" for example, at which point it gets a run time error 91, but it can still search google through IE until it reaches that point):
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r4faYmXfXGL5UPNgtg9Ku_e69wUslrC5sCW68eJSFqc/edit?usp=sharing
Haha so I'm a little confused to say the least!

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me, I am on my phone...

I see that you have set `oHtml` as a `New HTMLDocument` but I do not see it being provided it with any additional information.

Because of that I am assuming this code: `Set oElement = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")` is pretty much saying:

`Set oElement = Nothing` Which would cause a Run-Time Error 91.

As you are applying the innerText to the `html` object and not the `oHtml` object, I would try:

`Set oElement = html.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")`

Comment: Hmm, that appears to give me a new error! Haha I'll start an album with all the errors I generate :) . This time: "Run-time error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method"
Perhaps you cannot Set ```oElement = html``` but just to ```ohtml```

And I don't know if this matters or not, but the error actually comes at the next line
```Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = oElement(i).innerText```

Comment: This worked for you Tim? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong (wouldn't be the first haha!). So I simply deleted the o in front of html in this line ```Set oElement = ohtml.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")```. Then got the above error - '438'. I tried implementing your changes as well, but still got the error code.

Comment: Thank you so much aSIMetrical! You have both helped my sanity quite a bit, that was driving me mad!!!

Comment: No worries, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Change `html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP` to `oHtml.body.innerHTML = ...`

OR - change the `Set oElement = oHtml...`  to `Set oElement = html.getElementsByClassName()`

Then, change `oElement(i).innerText` to `oElement(0).innerText` since you want the first (`0` indexed) response from that class.